# How to update client endpoint binding in code

Tags: c#, web-services, binding, web-config

I have a question about modifying client endpoint binding in code.
I have added a web service reference and created a client endpoint binding for it.
In web.config I a binding set to basic https, which I want to change it to ex. http, which I have specified in web.config under the name "basicHttpBinding". When I create the instance of the web service reference, there is no way of using address and binding as there is not constructor that takes such arguments.

```
  <endpoint address="http://localhost/LocalService/SendRequest.asmx"
    binding="basicHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpsBinding"
    contract="LocalService.SendRequest" name="LocalServiceClient" />
```

Any advice how to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding() { Name = "LocalServiceClient", Namespace = "LocalService.SendRequest" };
var endPoint = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://localhost/LocalService/SendRequest.asmx");
var client = new ServiceClient(binding, endPoint);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, this is what you are looking for:

```
var x = new ServiceClient();
x.Endpoint.Binding = new BasicHttpBinding("optional configuration name");
```